# Is it necessary to write proof if one can refer to the database?

Tags: mathematics, formatting

I'm a final year undergraduate Math major. So now I am writing a paper about an application of Elliptic curve. You can see my research topic from this question in [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3850642/a-very-heavy-computation/3851571#3851571).

When studying the elliptic curve above, I'm following the theoretical result and approximation in *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* by Silverman and Tate. It details all calculations required to find the rank, torsion point, generator of infinite order of an elliptic curve. When I have almost done calculate all properties of the particular elliptic curve from my research project, I discover the LMFDB database, which has all information I wanted.

I would like to ask, is it necessary to put all calculations of mine in my paper, which is a duplicate effort from the book of Silverman and Tate? Or is it better just include the LMFDB database in my paper and discard these calculations? I think math papers are all about rigorous derivation, every gap should be properly filled, but I'm not sure is 'using database' an academic approach. Besides, I'm not worry about the length of my papers because I have some other original results.

Comment: When you say "paper" do you mean one written for a *course*, or something to be published as original research in an academic journal?

Comment: It is an undergraduate research, I want to publish it in some journal.

Comment: What did your advisor tell you when you asked them?

Comment: My advisor said I can put the calculations as appendix, but I think if someone found my paper useful, they were already familiar about how to do these calculations. So I'm not sure is it a good idea or not.

Comment: Assuming the result is publication-worthy without the extensive calculations you've done, maybe you could have two versions. One version is all the work you've done yourself, with all the details, and this would be what you submit for your honors project which, depending on the university, might be made available on some kind of honors thesis archive such as [this one](https://ecommons.udayton.edu/uhp_theses/), or which you could post yourself somewhere. This version could be of use to others wanting more details than in typical publications. The other version would be for publication.

Comment: For example, [this thesis](https://ecommons.udayton.edu/uhp_theses/225/) is probably not publication-worthy (too basic for research, too lengthy for publication in math exposition journals I know of), but I believe I actually recommended this (among other things) once to someone in Mathematics Stack Exchange asking for somewhere online for an introduction to Hausdorff and other dimensions and fractals.

Comment: I see. So do you think I will rather not put the duplicate calculation in my paper, right? Because I'm aiming for publication.

Comment: I don't know enough about this specific area of math to know whether this (duplicate calculation) is something you should include in the published version, which is why I didn't give any specifics or explanation about "version would be for publication". This is something you need to discuss with your advisor and/or others in this specific area. I guess my main point is to not let the extensive calculation version vanish, as others might be interested -- even you yourself in later years, in case you work on other things, and then want to get back to this particular topic.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind.